# Does the number of references change when calling data() of a qsharedpointer

Tags: c++, qt, qsharedpointer

If I write this code:

```
QSharedPointer<int> ptr(new int());
```

The number of references pointing to the integer is 1.
But when I call data() like this:

```
QSharedPointer<int> ptr(new int());   
int* ptr2 = ptr.data();
```

Is the number of references 1 or 2 ?
Thanks for help.

Comment: In terms of QSharedPointer caling data() does not increment reference count in that QSharedPointer, so if you call ptr.clear() then it will destroy the hold object and ptr2 will point to non existent data in memory. But there might be some ambiguousness in the question what do you mean by references - what is ref counts in QSharedPointer or how many variables are pointing to the object in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It won't change. [`QSharedPointer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html) only shares the pointer with `QSharedPointer`. It won't and can't share with raw pointer.

> QSharedPointer will delete the pointer it is holding when it goes out of scope, provided no other QSharedPointer objects are referencing it.

And [`QSharedPointer::data()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html) does nothing except

> Returns the value of the pointer referenced by this object.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `data()` does not change reference count. In fact, it doesn't really *do* anything. Its implementation is just this

```
inline T *data() const { return value; }
```

This is taken directly from [Qt sources](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qsharedpointer_impl.h#n301).